# SublimeText 3 Build System based on file path

Tags: python, sublimetext3, build-system

I need to run a different compiler dependent on which version of an app the file being edited is destined to be used with.

The source file is always stored in a path that contains the version number.

So file 
`%APPDATA%\App\9\Settings\Source.file`
Would need to run

```
%ProgramFiles%\App\9\Compiler.exe "%APPDATA%\App\9\Settings\Source.file"
```

and
`%APPDATA%\App\11\Settings\Source.file`
Would need to run

```
%ProgramFiles%\App\11\Compiler.exe "%APPDATA%\App\11\Settings\Source.file"
```

I have tried following the advanced example here:
https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html#advanced_example

but python really isnt my thing and I can't seem to get anything to run

Basic works but I cant specify the version:

```
    {
        "cmd": ["c:\\Program Files\\App\\10\\compile.exe", "$file"],
        "selector": "source.app",
        "file_patterns": "*.ext"
    }
```

But this doesnt:

```
        {
        "target": "app_build", 
        "selector": "source.app",
        "file_patterns": "*.ext"
    }
```

.py file

```py
    import sublime
    import sublime_plugin

    class AppBuildCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):

        def run (self):

            vars = self.window.extract_variables()
            compiler = vars['file_path']

            compiler = compiler.split("\\")

            compiler_path = "c:\\Program Files\\App\\" + compiler[compiler.index("App")+1] + "\\Compiler.exe"

            file = vars['file']

            self.window.run_command (compiler + " \"" + file + "\"")
```

Also tried with no success:

```
    args = []
    args.append(compiler)
    args.append(file)

    self.window.run_command("cmd", args)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `run_command()` method is for executing internal Sublime commands (i.e. the things you would bind to a key or trigger from a menu), so part of the reason why this isn't working for you is that you're trying to get Sublime to run a command instead of having it execute an external program.

A build system is normally executed by the `exec` command; this is essentially the default value of the `target` key if you don't provide it in your `sublime-build` file. `exec` is responsible for using the arguments given to it by Sublime to start up an external process, capture it's output and display it in the output panel at the bottom of the window.

In order to customize what gets executed, you do need to implement you own `WindowCommand` and use the `target` key to tell Sublime to run it, but that command is then responsible for doing what `exec` would do, which includes starting an external process and capturing the output.

The example that's listed in the documentation uses `subprocess.Popen()` to perform this task, along with having to track if the task is running to close it, etc.

An easy way to pull this off is to create your command as a subclass of the command that Sublime normally uses to run the build, so that you can customize how the build starts but let existing code take care of all of the details.

An example of such a command would be something like the following:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

import os

from Default.exec import ExecCommand


class AppBuildCommand(ExecCommand):
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        # Get the list of variables known to build systems
        variables = self.window.extract_variables()

        # Is there a file path? There won't be if the file hasn't been saved
        # yet.
        if "file_path" in variables:
            # Pull out the file path, split it into parts, and use the segment
            # after the "App" segment as the value of a new variable named
            # version.
            file_path = variables["file_path"].upper().split(os.sep)
            if "APP" in file_path:
                variables["version"] = file_path[file_path.index("APP") + 1]

        # Expand any remaining variables in our arguments and then execute the
        # build.
        kwargs = sublime.expand_variables(kwargs, variables)
        super().run(**kwargs)
```

An example of a `sublime-build` file that uses this command for the build would be:

```
{
    "target": "app_build",
    "cancel": {"kill": true},

    "cmd": ["c:\\Program Files\\App\\\\${version:100}\\compile.exe", "$file"],

    "selector": "source.app",
    "file_patterns": ["*.ext"]
}
```

The command itself examines the path of the current file for the segment that follows the `App` segment (here case insensitively just in case), and uses that to create a new build system variable named `version`. If the file hasn't been saved yet (and thus has no name on disk) or if there isn't a path segment named `App` in it, then the variable is not created.

The last two lines expand any variables that haven't been expanded yet, and then tell the `exec` command to execute the build.

The `sublime-build` file can be in every way a normal `sublime-build` file, but the changes you need to make are:

1. You need to use `target` to indicate that our command should be the one to execute
2. You should (but don't need to) set the `cancel` key to tell Sublime how to cancel your build if you choose the cancel build command; this one tells Sublime to execute the same `app_build` command that it used to start the build, but give it an extra argument to say the build should be terminated.
3. Anywhere you want to access the version number from the path of the file, use the notation `\\${version:DEFAULT}`.

The variable needs to be specified this way (i.e. with the two `\\` characters in front) because Sublime will automatically try to expand any variables in the build system keys that `exec` recognizes before it calls the command.

Since at the time the command gets called we haven't set the value of the `version` variable yet, this will make Sublime assume that the value is the empty string, which removes it from the string and stops us from being able to detect that it's there.

In order to get Sublime to leave the variable alone, you need to use the `\$` notation as an indication that this should not be treated as a special `$` character; Sublime will convert `\$` to `$` and pass it through to our command. In the `sublime-build` file you need to use `\\$` because `\$` is not a valid JSON character escape.

The `:DEFAULT` portion is optional; this is what will be used as the expanded text if the `version` variable isn't set. In the example above it's set to `100`, but in practice you'd set it to something like `9` or `11` instead. The variable won't be set if the command couldn't figure out the version to use, so you can use this to set a default version to be used in that case (if this makes sense for your use case).

This video series on [build systems in Sublime Text](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGfKZJVuHW91WyVIitRhcTPD1PTFIPsia) has more information in general on how build sytems work, which includes several videos on custom build targets and how they work, including more information on advanced custom targets that subclass the `ExecCommand` as we're doing here (disclaimer: I am the author).

Comment: That is amazing thanks.
The variable isnt being included in the command for some reason that I cant fathom but as I already know the full path I can overwrite the full command before running anyway.